# What is the kernel for a double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, path-integral, interference

In the book path integrals by Feynman and Hibbs, the author has established the kernel for a single slit in the Gaussian form. How can I find the kernel for a double slit in a similar fashion as described in the books?

Comment: Hi pyroscepter. In the future, please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Qmechanic, I'll keep that in mind. Sorry for the trouble caused.